# Linq: select property collection

Tags: linq, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have two classes:

```
public class Person
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public List<Order> Orders{get;set;}
}
public class Order
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string Data{get;set;}
   public decimal Sum{get;set;}
}
```

I use Nhibernate Linq. If I want to get total sum of orders filtering by Persan.Name I do this:

```
var result = (from person in personRepository.Query
             from order in person.Orders
             where person.Name.Contains("off")
             select order).Sum(order => order.Sum);
```

How can I do the same using fluent syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = personRepository.Query
    .Where(person => person.Name.Contains("off"))
    .SelectMany(person => person.Orders)
    .Sum(order => order.Sum);
```

If this solution throws an `ArgumentNullException` when there are no orders selected try this two step solution:

```
var orders = personRepository.Query
    .Where(person => person.Name.Contains("off"))
    .SelectMany(person => person.Orders);
var result = orders.Any()
    : orders.Sum(order => order.Sum)
    ? 0;
```

Comment: Thank you! Why application throws ArgumentNullException if count of selected orders is 0?