# Linq to NHibernate: sum of sums

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Having NHibernate entities:

`Company`, `Invoice` and `InvoiceLine` which has a decimal property `Price`.

A `Company` has a collection of type `Invoice`, and an `Invoice` has a collection of type `InvoiceLine`.

How can I obtain the sum of all prices that belong to invoice lines which belong to invoices of a certain company specified by id?

I tried to write the query like this:

```
session
    .Query<InvoiceLine>()
    .Where(invoiceLine => invoiceLine.Invoice.Company.Id == companyId)
    .Sum(invoiceLine => invoiceLine.Price);
```

but it throws an exception:

```
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException
"Could not execute query[SQL: SQL not available]"

   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(IQueryExpression queryExpression, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.List(IQueryExpression queryExpression, QueryParameters parameters)
   at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionQueryImpl.List()
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.ExecuteQuery(NhLinqExpression nhLinqExpression, IQuery query, NhLinqExpression nhQuery)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Sum[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 selector)
```

inner exception:

```
System.ArgumentNullException
"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: item"

   at System.ThrowHelper.IfNullAndNullsAreIllegalThenThrow[T](Object value, ExceptionArgument argName)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.System.Collections.IList.Add(Object item)
   at NHibernate.Util.ArrayHelper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<AddAll>b__0()
   at NHibernate.Util.ArrayHelper.AddAll(IList to, IList from)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLQueryPlan.PerformList(QueryParameters queryParameters, ISessionImplementor session, IList results)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(IQueryExpression queryExpression, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results)
```

This might have something to do with summing empty collections but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try casting the `Price` to nullable `decimal`...

```
.Sum(invoiceLine => (decimal?)invoiceLine.Price) ?? 0;
```

The result is clearly a `decimal?`

Comment: This is almost the solution, please change it to `.Sum(invoiceLine => (decimal?)invoiceLine.Price) ?? 0` so I can upvote and accept.

Answer (score 0):

The solution marked as answer didn't save the problem for me. Instead of GenericAdoException I got a InvalidOperationException with the following stack.

Proposed solution here [Linq: select property collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171394/linq-select-property-collection) is the actual solution for me.

```
Une erreur inattendue de type InvalidOperationException s'est produite sur le serveur
System.InvalidOperationException: Code supposed to be unreachable
   à System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
   à System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteUnaryExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack)
   à System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
   à System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpressionFreeTemps(Expression expression, Stack stack)
   à System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.Rewrite[T](Expression`1 lambda)
   à System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Accept(StackSpiller spiller)
   à System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile(LambdaExpression lambda, DebugInfoGenerator debugInfoGenerator)
   à System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Compile()
   à NHibernate.Linq.ExpressionToHqlTranslationResults.MergeLambdasAndCompile[TDelegate](IList`1 itemTransformers)
   à NHibernate.Linq.ExpressionToHqlTranslationResults..ctor(HqlTreeNode statement, IList`1 itemTransformers, IList`1 listTransformers, IList`1 postExecuteTransformers, List`1 additionalCriteria)
   à NHibernate.Linq.IntermediateHqlTree.GetTranslation()
   à NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.GenerateHqlQuery(QueryModel queryModel, VisitorParameters parameters, Boolean root)
   à NHibernate.Linq.NhLinqExpression.Translate(ISessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, Boolean filter)
   à NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   à NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryExpressionPlan.CreateTranslators(IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   à NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryExpressionPlan..ctor(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   à NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
   à NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)
   à NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)
   à NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression expression, IQuery& query, NhLinqExpression& nhQuery)
   à NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
   à NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   à System.Linq.Queryable.Sum[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 selector)
   à Secib.Server.Services.ReglementService.GetRegleTtc(FactureView facture) dans x:\Sources\Next\Alpha\SecibNext\Secib.Server\Services\ReglementService.cs:ligne 425
   à Secib.Server.Services.ReglementService.DoesMontantSoldeFacture(FactureView facture, Decimal montantImpute) dans x:\Sources\Next\Alpha\SecibNext\Secib.Server\Services\ReglementService.cs:ligne 391
   à Secib.Server.Services.ReglementService.DispatcheMontantImpute(Reglement reglement, ReglementFactureCompactDto factureDto) dans x:\Sources\Next\Alpha\SecibNext\Secib.Server\Services\ReglementService.cs:ligne 236
   à Secib.Server.Services.ReglementService.SaveReglement(Reglement reglement, IList`1 factures) dans x:\Sources\Next\Alpha\SecibNext\Secib.Server\Services\ReglementService.cs:ligne 197
   à Secib.Server.Controllers.ReglementController.<SaveReglement>z__OriginalMethod() dans x:\Sources\Next\Alpha\SecibNext\Secib.Server\Controllers\ReglementController.cs:ligne 141
   à Secib.Server.Controllers.ReglementController.<SaveReglement>c__Binding.Invoke(Object& instance, Arguments arguments, Object aspectArgs) dans :ligne 0
   à PostSharp.Aspects.Internals.MethodInterceptionArgsImpl`1.Proceed()
   à Secib.Server.Aspects.TransactionAspect.OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args) dans x:\Sources\Next\Alpha\SecibNext\Secib.Server\Aspects\TransactionAspect.cs:ligne 32
```

Comment: What inner exception where you getting and how did your query/entities look like? Unless something changed in the way it works, I'm pretty sure the accepted answer works.

Comment: That `SelectMany` second snipped of code is also making 2 requests to the DB instead of 1 (could be written using futures but it would still be less efficient).

Comment: InnerException is null. The query is very simple and very similar to yours : return Session.Query<ReglementFacture>()
    .Where(x => x.Facture == facture)
    .Sum(x => (decimal?)x.MontantRegle ?? 0); Where Facture is referenced by ReglementFacture (many to one) and MontantRegle is decimal (and the column is not nullable). NH v 4.0.0.4000

Comment: You need to call `??` on the entire query, not inside the sum lambda: `return Session.Query<ReglementFacture>() .Where(x => x.Facture == facture) .Sum(x => (decimal?)x.MontantRegle) ?? 0;` That is because Sum will return null when there are no elements in the collection. And you need to cast to `decimal?` because `Sum` can return null for empty collection and the return type is inferred from what type you return.

Answer (score -1):

```
session
    .Query<InvoiceLine>()
    .Where(invoiceLine => invoiceLine.Invoice.Company.Id == companyId && invoiceLine.Price != null)
    .Sum(invoiceLine => (decimal)invoiceLine.Price);
```

Comment: It throws exception not because there are null prices, but because database returns null when summing an empty collection. So this isn't gonna solve OP's issue.